# Is there a correct way to describe delta-v for a relativistic spacecraft?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, spaceships, terminology

So if I have a spaceship that has an extremely powerful e.g. antimatter rocket (*not* FTL, relativity applies) and can accelerate up to say 60% of light-speed, then coast to Alpha Centauri, then decelerate back to zero... well, it can't be right to say the spaceship has a delta-v capacity of 120% of light-speed, can it?

Because that would imply it could accelerate to 120% of light-speed if it didn't care about slowing down again, which would violate relativity.

So what's the correct way to describe this capability? Is there such a thing as relativistic delta-v, or would some other term need to be used?

Comment: I've added a tag, feel free to revert if you see fit.

Comment: Are you interested in the delta-v for the sake of calculating the ratio of initial mass with fuel to final payload mass, or for some other calculation?

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_rocket#Relativistic_rocket_equation is relevant?  Given that there is a way of calculating delta-v for relativistic situations and the relevant professionals can be expected to know whether non-relativistic (ordinary) delta-v or relativistic delta-v is being used in any given situation, it doesn't seem like an issue to have a non-relativistic delta-v greater than the speed of light.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan - If you use delta-v > c in the relativistic version of the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation on that page (which is also discussed in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation#Special_relativity) of the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation page), you get the physically meaningless conclusion that the ratio of m0 (initial mass including fuel) to m1 (final payload mass with fuel expended) would be an imaginary number.

Comment: (cont.) For a problem where a rocket does two linear accelerations in different directions, the first one giving it a velocity v relative to its rest frame at the start, the second a velocity u relative to its rest frame at the beginning of the second acceleration, I think for the purpose of the Tsiolkovsky eq. you'd want to imagine what its delta-v relative to the starting frame would be if both accelerations had been in the *same* direction, using the [relativistic velocity addition](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/velocity.html) formula.

Comment: "that would imply " - no it would not there is no ground for confusion, it just delta-v and it says most about your capacitive in terms of energy and reactive mass. Diamond Eyes answer clarifies that well enough.

Comment: It just a fancy way of saying dude look my rocket can reach Mars at full tank! T&C apply: assume flat space-time and no external forces are acting on it ;D

Comment: Note that an antimatter rocket of the sort you're talking about here will need an astoshing amount of antimatter to get the sort of delta-V you're interested in. Fast interstellar travel isn't really practical with any sort of rocket. Use beam propulsion to go, magnetic breaking to stop, and save your antimatter to run a lower-Isp engine for in-system manoevering when you arrive.

Comment: '... can accelerate up to say 60% of light-speed...' How do you know how fast you are going? And '...light speed...' relative to what? And exactly what do you think will happen when you 'violate relativity'? Current theory says that, with the increasing expansion of the universe, eventually galaxies will travel away from each other at a 'velocity' greater than 'c'. There are no 'relativity police'. It's just an Einsteinian Religion proscriptive thing.

Comment: @StarfishPrime yeah, I didn't want to get into the details of that because it's not really relevant to the specific question, but I am aware.

Comment: @Hypnosifl my question is more about how it would be described, rather than how to calculate it. I mean, do we need to start using some term other than "delta-v" once we get into relativistic velocities, since we can't just add up the velocity change for each burn anymore (0.6c + 0.6c = 1.2c ... but obviously the ship can't accelerate to 1.2c)?

Comment: You can add the velocities, you just have to understand that in relativity the addition of velocities v and u is given by the [relativistic velocity addition formula](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/velocity.html) (v+u)/(1+vu/c^2) and not just by (v+u) as it would be in classical mechanics.

Comment: @Hypnosifl yeah, that's my problem - the "total change in velocity if you burn to depletion" is different if you just accelerate until you run out of fuel, vs. if you accelerate then decelerate. So is there a *single* number that can describe the total "delta-v capacity" of the spacecraft?

Comment: Decelerating is just turning your ship around backwards and firing the rocket (accelerating) in the opposite direction. So suppose you accelerate to 0.6c relative to the Earth, coast, and turn around backwards and accelerate until you're moving at 0.6c relative to an observer at rest in the coasting frame (meaning you come to rest relative to Earth). Then that should use the exact same amount of fuel as if you accelerate to 0.6 relative to Earth, coast, then *don't* turn around but just accelerate in the same direction until you're moving at 0.6c relative to the observer in the coasting frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**, as long as each burn doesn't get too far into relativistic speeds, you can go back and forth to a sub light speed enough times to add up to more than 1c.

Long answer: Depends on how you look at it! I like to use [Rapidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity)

If the non-relativistic Tsiolkovsky equation gives you a delta-V of 2c, that's fine, though you still ***cannot ever go faster than the speed of light by using Newtonian means!*** You can only achieve faster than c velocities by warping space or using wormholes. Delta-V is a measure of how much velocity change you have, not total final speed, which is limited by relativity.

Explaining further can get very technical, but to do my best, here goes: what you do is you add coefficients of the speed of light (v/c) and find the hyperbolic tangent of that value.

tanh(x) only gets to 1 at infinity, so, any sum inside of it will only ever approach 1.

Examples:

If your total dv is 2c, your v is 2c and c is still c, so 2/1 = 2. How fast can you go if you made a single burn in one direction? Since tanh(2) = 0.96402758007... c, you can get to almost 97% the speed of light! Quite fast, but good luck slowing down.

Now, let's take the other approach. "How many times can I go to .1c and back?" .1c/1c = .1/1 = .1, simply enough, since we're already using a coefficient of c to look at speed. [2 / (tanh^(-1)(.1))] = 19.9332... so you can do it *almost* 20 times.

Why almost 20 and not actually 20? Because going to 10% the speed of light 19 times has some additive relativistic effect.

If you want me to go even deeper into detail with reference frames for a stationary observer relative to the ship speeding up, slowing down, and coming back, that goes far beyond my abilities.

Comment: I have no Idea what you are saying or how this might answer the question. The numbers seem to make no sense, not to mention the reverse-capitalization.

Comment: Have you heard of rapidity?

Comment: Please see my edits to the answer.

Comment: That's nice, it works as an answer as you've added the term " rapidity " with a link. Terms are what the OP was asking for after all. +1

Comment: When you say "If a normal rocket equation gives you a dV of 2c", does "normal rocket equation" refer to the non-relativistic Tsiolkovsky equation, non-relativistic velocity addition, or something else?

Comment: Ah, it ate my comment. Did the edits explain it better?

Comment: OK, "rapidity" helps, I think, but I am still not sure exactly how that lines up with delta-V

Comment: Rapidity matters when you start dealing with things getting too close to light speed, basically. Otherwise, you aren't accounting for how relativity starts warping everything to stop you from ever really getting to the speed of light. When you aren't anywhere near it, the difference is so negligible you might as well ignore it. 

If your non-relativistic delta v is 2c, what that really means when you do account for relativity depends on how close to the speed of light you get. That's why I gave the examples showing how you can go to .1c and back nearly 20 times, or 94.6% of light speed once.

Comment: In the edit, when you say "If the non-relativistic Tsiolkovsky equation gives you a dV of 2c", do you mean actually solving the equation for dV (which would require already knowing the ratio of initial to final mass), or do you just mean a problem where the rocket does two different burns with different changes in velocity dV1 and dV2, so in a classical problem you could just define the total dV as dV1 + dV2 and then plug that into the classical Tsiolkovsky equation to solve for the ratio of initial mass before either burn to final mass after both burns?

Comment: And if it's the latter, are you using rapidity as a different mathematical technique for answering the exact same question that is being addressed when people use the [relativistic velocity addition formula](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/velocity.html), or are you calculating something different? If it's something different, any chance you could give a numerical example?

Comment: @DiamondEyes yes, I get that concept. But how do I use that to summarize the potential performance of a spacecraft (the way I can use delta-v capacity for real-life ones that don't get anywhere near relativistic velocities)?

Comment: I don't think it's correct that rapidity tells you what the speed would be in relativity if you plug in the speed that classical physics predicts you'd have given some combo of accelerations. For example, suppose I accelerate from 0 to (2/3)c in frame A, then in frame B where I'm now initially at rest I again accelerate to (2/3)c in the same direction, and in frame C where I'm now initially at rest I do the same thing again. Then classically my speed would be 3 times (2/3)c, or 2c. But if you use the relativistic velocity addition formula, you don't get 0.96402758c but rather 0.98412698c.

Comment: I always reserve the right to be wrong! Admittedly this is at the very limits of my knowledge.

I'm going off of old notes and chatting with a researcher, who explained it to me as "hyperbolically rotating the non relativistic rocket equation."

Comment: Thank you. Post-edits, with the rapidity part, I'm now accepting this